# uwp page access voilation exception on initializecomponent

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-store

so I have a **uwp app** in the store. it was all running fine and then I made some changes to it to make a update. still it was running fine then I uploaded the updated package to the store and store certification failed and according to the report. when one of my pages is navigated to the app crashes.

I kept trying but I was not able to reproduce the issue on my machine, then today I just uninstalled the app , cleaned the project and ran the app again and I saw that when I try to navigated to that made I get an exception.

**AccesVoilation, attempted to read or write memory, this means that memory may be corrupt.**

Now I am not able to find the cause of this, and I don't know what code to show here, because there not even any stacktrace of the exception. when I click on exception details , the debugging automatically stops.

**CODE**
This is my code for that pages constructor

```
public ShellPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = ViewModel;
        if (Windows.Foundation.Metadata.ApiInformation.IsApiContractPresent("Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract", 5))
        {
            NavigationMenu.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ViewModel.Initialize(newShellFrame);
        }
        else
        {
            ViewModel.Initialize(shellFrame);// for creators update
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE** a strange behaviour is, sometimes I get this exception and sometimes I don't :/

**UPDATE 2**

**stackTrace**

at Windows.UI.Xaml.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator, ComponentResourceLocation componentResourceLocation)\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.Views.ShellPage.InitializeComponent()\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.Views.ShellPage..ctor()\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.FluentVideoPlayer_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_89_ShellPage()\r\n   at FluentVideoPlayer.FluentVideoPlayer_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()"  string

Comment: So if you are not able to find the cause of this with the source code, the debugger and the logs imagine us that all we have is your short message complaining :D

Comment: If you can see the stacktrace of the exception might be is because the exception happens in native mode, try to enable mixed debugging. Other actions could be to generate a crash dump and analyze it.

Comment: @IgnacioSolerGarcia I understand its not a very helpful question, I just posted it in hopelessness :( how can I enable mixed debugging? also I am trying to reproduce the issue and now I cant reproduce it, but somehow the store team always reproduces it.

Comment: Please post some code. If the problem happens randomly, and also it is a `AccessViolationException`, it is very likely you are accessing a UI element from another thread.

Comment: what I don't understand is that exception occurs on InitializeComponent() so it is not happening in any code I wrote myself, and the error u r mentioning is usually "marshall threading error " which is solved with Dispatcher , right? tht is why I don't know what code to show here as the exception occurs on InitializeComponent() and it doesnt even reach any code written by me. @MartinZikmund

Comment: I'm thinking if that problem couldn't be somewhere inside navigation from the previous page for example? I think it is the Access Violation exception in thread scenario as well, but it is weird it is happening at InitializaComponent. My suspicion is that it is not actually happening there, but just at the same time. But hard to say. Any code would help :-)

Comment: actually it is the first page in my root frame so doesnt really come from another page and when it comes from another page, the exception still occurs, ok let me open the app and try to show u some code.

Comment: @MartinZikmund have a look I have put some code.

Comment: If you can't get exception, you could  try debug in the `Mixed` model. Right click your project -->Properties-->Debug-->Debuger Type--Application process-->Mixed.

Comment: yes thankyou @NicoZhu-MSFT but tht will only be helpful if I am able to reproduce this problem which I can't now, I was able to reproduce it before accidently and now again its gone, but the store team always seem to reproduce it.

Comment: @MartinZikmund please see the update I was able to get the stacktrace , maybe it helps a little?